# PHP замена текста из массива файлов

Tags: php

Есть форма с двумя инпутами - исходное значение и заменяемое, форма отправляет GET в файл replace.php

```
<?php

  $text = $_GET['mac1']; // Искомая строка
  $retext = $_GET['mac2']; // Строка замены
  $files = array(
      "v301.conf", 
      "v302.conf", 
      "v303.conf", 
      "v304.conf", 
      "v305.conf", 
      "v306.conf", 
      "v307.conf", 
      "v308.conf", 
      "v309.conf", 
      "v310.conf", 
      "v311.conf", 
      "v312.conf", 
      "v313.conf"
  ); // Массив файлов, в которых искать и заменять 

  if($text !== "" && $retext !== ""){ // Если исходный и заменяемый тексты не пустые
    foreach($files as $f){ // получаем имена файлов
        $filename = $f;
        $file = file_get_contents($filename); // открываем каждый файл
        $file = str_replace($text, $retext, $file); // заменяем текст
        file_put_contents($filename, $file); // перезаписываем файл 
       echo "Значение в файле ".$f." заменено <br>";
    }


  } else {
    echo "Параметры для замены не найдены!";  
  }


?>
```

При замене текста, даже если в каком то из файлов его нет, срабатывает echo, что в этом файле текст заменен...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотнее отобразить оповещение только о тех файлах, в которых значение было изменено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте 4й параметр функции замены, он возвращает число произведенных замен. Соответственно, если оно равно нулю, то замен не было.

```
if($text != $repl){

    $total = 0;
    foreach($files as $f){
        $content = file_get_contents($f);

        $count = 0;
        $content = str_replace($text, $repl, $content, $count); 

        if($count){
             file_put_contents($f, $content); 

             echo "Значение в файле ".$f." заменено <br>";
             $total += $count;
        } 
    }

    if(!$total){
         echo "ничего не заменено"
    }
}
else {
    echo "Параметры для замены не найдены!";  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!